# SvnAnt and proxy

Tags: svn, ant, proxy

I am trying to do some automation of our build and deployement process. For that, I use [SvnAnt](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html). Our SVN repository is accessible via HTTPS, through our corporate proxy. This proxy require authentication.

In my `<Home Folder>\Application Data\Subversion\servers` I have :

```
[global]
http-proxy-host = proxy.mynetwork.com
http-proxy-port = 8080
```

I have a test target :

```
<target name="test-svn" depends="svn-password, proxy-password">
    <svn username="${user.name}"
         password="${svn.password}">
        <update dir="${basedir}" recurse="true" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

I have the following error :

```
test-svn:
  [svn] <Update> started ...
  [svn] svn: CONNECT request failed on 'http://proxy.mynetwork.com:8080'
  [svn] svn: CONNECT of 'subversion.othernetwork.com:443': 407 Proxy Authentication Required (https://subversion.othernetwork.com)
  [svn] svn: CONNECT request failed on 'http://proxy.mynetwork.com:8080'
  [svn] svn: CONNECT of 'subversion.othernetwork.com:443': 407 Proxy Authentication Required (https://subversion.othernetwork.com)
  [svn] <Update> failed !

BUILD FAILED
```

If I add my user name and password to `<Home Folder>\Application Data\Subversion\servers` it works :

```
http-proxy-username = myuser
http-proxy-password = mypassword
```

But ... I dont want to store my password unencrypted.

So I tried to add a proxy to my ant target directly :

```
<target name="test-svn" depends="svn-password, proxy-password">
    <setproxy proxyhost="${proxy.host}"
              proxyport="${proxy.port}"
              proxyuser="${user.name}"
              proxypassword="${proxy.password}" />
    <svn username="${user.name}"
         password="${svn.password}">
        <update dir="${basedir}" recurse="true" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

But I have the same error than in the first case. Is there any way around that ?